# Combining pure predicates

Tags: prolog, logical-purity

I am trying to combine some pure predicates from previous stack overflow questions to make my own predicate.

I want to give a list of c's (which have associated facts -'ats' with them) and a 'feature' term which has an operator and a threshold for an 'at' . I want to partition the lists of c's, if the c does not have the corresponding 'at' from the 'feature' it will go in the false partition, otherwise the operator will test the 'at' for that 'c' and  splits the c's appropriately.

For example:

```
?-cpgpartition_ts_fs_feature([c1,c2,c3],Ts,Fs,feature(at2,_,>=,10)).
```

Should result in :

```
Ts = [c3], %c3 has an at2 >= 10
Fs = [c1,c2]. %c1 has at2 <10 and c2 does not have an at2
```

This is the code I have:

```
:-use_module(library(clpfd)).

cpgpartition_ts_fs_feature([],[],[],_).
cpgpartition_ts_fs_feature([X|Xs0],Ts,Fs,Feature):-
    Feature = feature(At,_,Op,FValue),
    cpg_ats_i(X,AtList),
    atom_concat(#,Op,Op2), %make clpfd operator
    Test =..[Op2,AtValue3,FValue],
    if_(memberd_t(attribute(At,AtValue3),AtList),
       (
       if_(call(Test), (Ts=[X|Ts0],Fs=Fs0),
       (   Ts =Ts0,Fs=[X|Fs0]))
       )
       ,Fs=[X|Fs0]),
    cpgpartition_ts_fs_feature(Xs0,Ts0,Fs0,Feature).

if_(If_1, Then_0, Else_0) :-
   call(If_1, T),
   (  T == true -> call(Then_0)
   ;  T == false -> call(Else_0)
   ;  nonvar(T) -> throw(error(type_error(boolean,T),_))
   ;  /* var(T) */ throw(error(instantiation_error,_))
   ).

bool01_t(1,true).
bool01_t(0,false).

=(X, Y, T) :-
   (  X == Y -> T = true
   ;  X \= Y -> T = false
   ;  T = true, X = Y
   ;  T = false,
      dif(X, Y)                             % ISO extension
      % throw(error(instantiation_error,_)) % ISO strict
   ).

#=<(X,Y,Truth) :- X #=< Y #<==> B, bool01_t(B,Truth).

#<( X,Y,Truth) :- X #<  Y #<==> B, bool01_t(B,Truth).

#>( X,Y,Truth) :- X #>  Y #<==> B, bool01_t(B,Truth).

#>=(X,Y,Truth) :- X #>= Y #<==> B, bool01_t(B,Truth).

list_memberd_t([]    ,_,false).
list_memberd_t([Y|Ys],X,Truth) :-
   if_(X=Y, Truth=true, list_memberd_t(Ys,X,Truth)).

list_memberd_truth(Xs,X,Truth) :- list_memberd_t(Xs,X,Truth).

memberd_t(X,Xs,Truth) :- list_memberd_t(Xs,X,Truth).

value_intvalue(attribute(_A,X),attribute(_A,Y)):-
        AtValue2 is X *100, %Convert decimal number to integer.
        Y is integer(AtValue2).

cpg_ats_i(C,AtList):-
        cpg_ats(C,Ats),
        maplist(value_intvalue,Ats,AtList).

cpg_ats(c1,[attribute(at1,0.5),attribute(at2,0.03)]).
cpg_ats(c2,[attribute(at1,0.02)]).
cpg_ats(c3,[attribute(at2,0.1),attribute(at3,0.04),attribute(at4,0.08)]).
```

When trying the test query I get:

```
cpgpartition_ts_fs_feature([c1,c2,c3],Ts,Fs,feature(at2,_,>=,10)).
Fs = [c1, c2] ;
Fs = [c1, c2, c3] ;
Fs = [c1, c2] ;
Fs = [c1, c2, c3].
```

And interestingly the results change if the order of the clist is different.

```
?- cpgpartition_ts_fs_feature([c3,c1,c2],Ts,Fs,feature(at2,_,>=,10)).
Ts = [c3|_12950],
Fs = [c1, c2] ;
Ts = [c3|_12950],
Fs = [c1, c2] ;
Fs = [c3, c1, c2] ;
Fs = [c3, c1, c2].
```

I think this is because the following query returns results with `dif/2` constraints which seem inappropriate for what I am trying to do, I only want the concrete solutions.

```
    ?- cpg_ats_i(C,Ats),   if_(memberd_t(attribute(at2,AtValue),Ats),Q=true,Q=false).
C = c1,
Ats = [attribute(at1, 50), attribute(at2, 3)],
AtValue = 3,
Q = true ;
C = c1,
Ats = [attribute(at1, 50), attribute(at2, 3)],
Q = false,
dif(AtValue, 3) ;
C = c2,
Ats = [attribute(at1, 2)],
Q = false ;
C = c3,
Ats = [attribute(at2, 10), attribute(at3, 4), attribute(at4, 8)],
AtValue = 10,
Q = true ;
C = c3,
Ats = [attribute(at2, 10), attribute(at3, 4), attribute(at4, 8)],
Q = false,
dif(AtValue, 10).
```

Also the aim is for this code to run on a large set of data, the c's list will be hundreds of thousands in length and each c might have 50k of ats, how can I work out the memory requirements? and is a different approach using impure predicates likely to take less memory?

Comment: At first glance, replace `Test =..[Op2,AtValue3,FValue], ..., call(Test)` by `call(Op2,AtValue3,FValue)`

Comment: Done. But it does not seem to make a difference ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned the problem is in the dif(X,Y) line in the definition of:

```
=(X, Y, T) :-
   (  X == Y -> T = true
   ;  X \= Y -> T = false
   ;  T = true, X = Y
   ;  T = false,
      dif(X, Y)                             % ISO extension
      % throw(error(instantiation_error,_)) % ISO strict
   ).
```

that's because if you try:

```
memberd_t(attribute(at2,X),[attribute(at1,0.5),attribute(at2,0.03)],T).
X = 0.03,
T = true ;
T = false,
dif(X, 0.03).
```

Here the choice point that gives the solution: `T = false,dif(X, 0.03).` will lead to execute the part `Fs=[X|Fs0]` of the:

```
if_(memberd_t(attribute(At,AtValue3),AtList),
       (
       if_(call(Test), (Ts=[X|Ts0],Fs=Fs0),
       (   Ts =Ts0,Fs=[X|Fs0]))
       )
       ,Fs=[X|Fs0]),
```

Also this is not right response since if you have attribute(at2,0.03) in the `Atlist` you expect `memberd_t` to return `X = 0.03, T = true` which will trigger the `Then_0` part of `if_/3` (and no other solution with T = false that will lead to other choice points executing Else_0 part).

So you could remove the  `T = false,dif(X, Y)`   of `=/3` and now let's try:

```
?- cpgpartition_ts_fs_feature([c1,c2,c3],Ts,Fs,feature(at2,_,>=,10)).
Fs = [c1, c2].
```

good but where is Ts??

***So there is another bug:***

The above says that it succeeds for `Fs = [c1,c2]` and **for every Ts**. That's because executing `Else_0` part of `if_/3` which fulfills the `Fs` list you don't restrict `Ts` list just leave as `Ts` and later call `cpgpartition_ts_fs_feature(Xs0,Ts0,Fs0,Feature)` with another `Ts0` list independent of Ts. So add:

```
if_(memberd_t(attribute(At,AtValue3),AtList),
       (
        if_(call(Test), (Ts=[X|Ts0],Fs=Fs0), (Ts =Ts0,Fs=[X|Fs0]))
       )
       ,(Fs=[X|Fs0], Ts = Ts0 )),
                     ^^^^^^^^
                     here added
```

Finally I as recommended by @false it is better replace `Test =..[Op2,AtValue3,FValue], ..., call(Test)` by `call(Op2,AtValue3,FValue)` since `call/N` is part of ISO and it fits into the original Mycroft O'Keefe type system.

Now let's try again:

```
?- cpgpartition_ts_fs_feature([c1,c2,c3],Ts,Fs,feature(at2,_,>=,10)).
Ts = [c3],
Fs = [c1, c2].
```

Seems right and deterministic :) !!.

As for the memory part of your question I'm not so sure but prefer deterministic predicates that don't leave choice points for memory efficiency. Using pure predicates will make you program more relational and will have better behavior but I'm not so sure if `if_/3` is so memory efficient since it contains many calls but I'm not sure maybe someone else could answer this part more clearly.

Comment: Great spot! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the answer from Coder I came up with:

```
cpgpartition_ts_fs_feature([],[],[],_).
cpgpartition_ts_fs_feature([X|Xs0],Ts,Fs,feature(At,_,Op,FValue)):-
    cpg_ats_i(X,AtList),
    atom_concat(#,Op,Op2), %make clpfd operator
    maplist(atterm_atname,AtList,Ats),
    if_(memberd_t(At,Ats),
      (
      memberchk(attribute(At,AtValue3),AtList),
      if_(call(Op2,AtValue3,FValue), (Ts=[X|Ts0],Fs=Fs0),
        (   Ts =Ts0,Fs=[X|Fs0]))
      ),
      (Fs=[X|Fs0],Ts=Ts0)
    ),
    cpgpartition_ts_fs_feature(Xs0,Ts0,Fs0,feature(At,_,Op,FValue)).


atterm_atname(attribute(At,_),At).
```

Which allowed me to get the same result without changing the definition of `=/3`.

Answer (score 0):

The current suggested implementation of if_/3 is botched, since
it puts a choice point on the reification, instead on the 
if-then-else itsef. Here is an example flaw:

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.1.4)

?- call(','(X=Y,2=3),B).
X = Y,
B = false ;  %%% a bloody choice point %%%
B = false,
dif(X, Y).
```

Here we see a much better intelligence for the conjunction 
of for example #/\ from CLP(FD) in SWI-Prolog. No choice
point is created:

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.1.4)

?- X #= Y #/\ 2 #= 3 #<==> B.
B = 0,
X in inf..sup,
Y in inf..sup.
```

I am currently working on a better if_/3, that incorporates
this kind of intelligence into its working. The basic pattern
for the better if_/3 will be:

```
if(Cond, Then, Else) :-
   reify(Cond, Bool),
   thenelse(Bool, Then, Else)

thenelse(1, Then, _) :- Then.
thenelse(0, _, Else) :- Else.
```

The idea is to **not** put any choice points into reify/2,
avoid them as long as possible. Currently (=)/3 creates
a choice point, which is not good when combining

condinition. Maybe we can also arrange that the same conditions
at different places in the code, share the same boolean
indicator variable. Working on it...